# Чему равно свойство length (в строках a, b) массива r.?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос из задачника, но в коде нет b?

```js
var r = ['a','l','p','h'];
r.length = 10;
// a . r.length = ?


delete r[0];
   
   // b. r.length = ?
```

Варианты ответов -

a. 10 b. 10

a. 4 b. 3

a. 10 b.9

a undefined b undefined

Правильный: a 10 b 10 - почему так?

Если вызвать `console.log(r);` до удаления и после

```js
var r = ['a','l','p','h'];
r.length = 10;
console.log(r);

delete r[0];
console.log(r);
```

то выведет:

(10) ["a", "l", "p", "h", empty × 6]

(10) [empty, "l", "p", "h", empty × 6] // после   delete r[0];

И где же строка b?

Comment: С помощью `a` и `b` просто пометили значение `r.length` в разные моменты времени, это не переменные, просто обозначение задачника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a и b - это "номера" задачек.

r.length = 10 - это мы задаём длинну массива и когда в пункте а) вас спрашиваю какая длинна массива, то ответ 10, так как мы её увеличели до 10.

В пункте b) мы удаляем нулевой элемент массива, но с помощью delete мы можем его только затереть, а длинна останется прежней - 10.

Answer (score 2):

"a" и "b"  в ответах - это значения `r.length` в местах, помеченных `// a.` и `// b.`.